# Separate charts for element in list using ggplot2 and lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

Okay guys I need a hand with using ggplot2 in a loop over a list (with lapply)  to obtain a separate chart for each element of the list.
I'm new to R, so forgive the noob-ness.

Say I have a dataframe as such:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(Time = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), 
Person = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), 
Quantity = c(1,4,6,8,1,6,2,10))

df <- data.table(df)

> df
   Time Person Quantity
1:    1      A        1
2:    2      A        4
3:    3      A        6
4:    4      A        8
5:    1      B        1
6:    2      B        6
7:    3      B        2
8:    4      B       10
```

I want to produce a chart for person A and person B separately.
At the moment I have my function set up like this:

```
Persons = c("A","B")
PersonList = as.list(Persons)


MyFunction <- function(x){

SubsetPersons = Persons[!(Persons %in% x)]
df <- df[!(df$Person %in% SubsetPersons)]

g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time, y=Quantity))
g <- g + geom_line()
print(g)

}

Results <- lapply(Persons, MyFunction)
```

But I'm not sure how to save the charts with different names corresponding to the list elements?

NOTE: I know this function may seem an odd way to solve this problem, but for the larger more complex problem I have at hand it is required.
I am simply trying to figure out how to save different names for the charts in the list!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you say "save the charts", do you mean saving the graphical output to a file, or keeping the variable (i.e. `g` above)?

Comment: Ultimately I want to save them to a file. But I guess even if they are just called different names like gA and gB then I can call upon them later and save them...

Comment: But yes, I think saving them to the directory straight away in pdf or png format would probably be helpful!

Comment: you can explore `ggsave` and creating different file name each time in the function.

Comment: That's the problem I have though, I'm not sure how to save it with a different name each time in the function...... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Persons = c("A","B")

MyFunction <- function(x){

  dfs <- df[df$Person == x,]

  g <- ggplot(data=dfs, aes(x=Time, y=Quantity))
  g <- g + geom_line()

#have added extra bracket after ".PNG"
  ggsave(paste0("plot_for_person", x, ".PNG"), g)

  print(g)

  return(g)

}

Results <- lapply(Persons, MyFunction)
```

Comment: You may need to require require(data.table) to run my code.

Your code worked perfect, just had to add an extra bracket after ".PNG"

Comment: ah yes sorry about that. Also didn't notice your earlier code segment with data table and `df`, have changed the variable in the function to `dfs` to avoid confusion.

Comment: would you be able to advise how to save the variable "g" above? So that each "g" actually has a differentname.. eg.. "gA", "gB" etc?

Comment: It is not advisable to save under different names, which would make it difficult to automate (both generation, and further processing).

It may be better to save it as elements of a list, so you have `g[[1]]`, `g[[2]]`, etc for various `g`.

I have edited my answer to add `return(g)` at the end. If you run the `lapply`, I believe your `Results` should now be a list of n elements each of which is a `g`, where n is the number of elements in `Persons`